# Change in MVC ListBoxFor behaviour between projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding

Im wondering if anyone can explain the following disparity in functionality between two ASP.Net MVC 3 projects.

In both projects I have a view model which contains the following:

```
public List<int> Questions;
```

And in both projects I have the following ListBoxFor code:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Questions, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Questions as List<MyStandardLib.Mvc.Attribute>, "Id", "Name", @Model.Questions), new { @class = "ui-field-multiselect", style = "width: 250px;" })
```

The difference in functionality is that when run, one project binds the existing selected Questions correctly, the other does not and shows all Questions as unselected.  Stepping through the code, the List is populated in the view and is correctly passed to the MultiSelectList constructor, but it isn't setting the values as selected.

This is really frustrating.

Comment: Are you instantiating your list properly in both?

Comment: The List is valid and in existence when the view is populated - I can step through the view and see that List<int> Question contains items at all times.  Checking the source of the outputted page shows no selected value on the dropdown, just the list of questions.

Comment: ViewBag.Questions isnt a List<int>, Model.Questions is.

Comment: What happens if you change you `ViewBag.Questions` variable name to `ViewBag.AvailableQuestions`?  I've seen cases where the renderer gets confused about what variable you are referring to.

Comment: yeah sorry I deleted that comment it wasn't well thought out

Comment: Jeremy, looks I was just testing that while you were typing it - it is indeed that which is causing it, but only in one project, how very odd!

Comment: Seems odd that it would mix up ViewBag.Questions and Model.Questions - unless there is an assumed link between ViewBag and the Model that Im unaware of...

Comment: Do you want to add that as the answer and Ill accept it :)

Comment: @in a model-less view, the ViewBag is used for the View data, so the helper looks in both places.  The lesson here is avoid naming related data the same thing, I guess.  :)

Comment: That is plausible, but still stupid as you cannot just reference "Questions" in the view, can you?  Surely it has scope, whether its ViewBag. or Model. ?

Comment: I expect it has something to do with the dynamic nature of the ViewBag, but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ViewBag.Questions` variable name to `ViewBag.AvailableQuestions`.  Sometimes the renderer gets confused about what you are referring to.